# How to Fix DataTables warning: table id=detailDataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables, cdn

Here my code, i got error DataTables warning: table id=detailDataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#detailDataTable').DataTable({
        "columns":
        [
            {   'data': 'TAG_NUMBER', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'TAG_NUMBER' },
            {   'data': 'ASSET_NUMBER', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'ASSET_NUMBER' },
            {   'data': 'ASSET_DESCRIPTION', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'ASSET_DESCRIPTION' },
            {   'data': 'PIC', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'PIC' },
            {   'data': 'LANTAI', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'LANTAI' },
            {   'data': 'RUANGAN', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'RUANGAN' },
            {
                'data': 'IMAGE',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return `<td><img class="modalImage" style="max-height: 150px; object-fit: cover;" 
                    src="/api/images?q=${row.TAG_NUMBER}&s=${$("#dbName").val()}"/></td>`;
                },
                "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'IMAGE'
            },
            {   'data': 'KETERANGAN', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'KETERANGAN' },
            {   'data': 'CREATED_BY', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'CREATED_BY' },
            {   'data': 'CREATED_DATE', "defaultContent": "", 'title': 'CREATED_DATE' }
        ],
        "columnDefs": 
        [
            {
                "targets": 0, // your case first column
                "width": "4%"
            },
            {
                "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], // all column
                "className": "text-center",
            }
        ]
    });
});
```